# Javascript event listener - run code after event finish bubbling

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I would like to run some code after event finish to bubble up the DOM for example

```
    document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
       // run some code after event finish to bubble up
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You have at least two choices:

1. Queue an async task (`setTimeout` or a Promise resolution)
2. Handle the event on `document`, but only if it passed through #myBtn en route to it; this isn't technically when it's *fully* completed bubbling, just at the final stage of it

Note that some actions that must be in response to a user event (such as opening a window) may or may not work with #1.

Here's #1 using a Promise:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        // Do the work here
    });
});
```

The advantage to using a promise resolution is that on compliant browsers, the promise resolution will be run before any other queued events. (Promise resolutions are *microtasks* that run after the current task but before the next task.) So it'll run before any event handler callback for elements the event bubbles to. But that may not fit your definition of "after event finish bubble up the DOM." If not, use `setTimeout` instead, because it queues a task (not a microtask):

Here's an example of both:

```js
document.getElementById("promiseButton").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    console.log(`button click on #${event.currentTarget.id}`);
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
          console.log("promise fulfillment");
    });
});
document.getElementById("timeoutButton").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    console.log(`button click on #${event.currentTarget.id}`);
    setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("timer callback");
    }, 0);
});
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    console.log("document click");
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="promiseButton" value="Using promise">
<input type="button" id="timeoutButton" value="Using setTimeout">
```

Here's #2:

```
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const node = event.target.closest("#myBtn");
    if (node) {
        // Do the work here
    }
});
```

Note that if the event is handled before it bubbles to the document and the handler uses `stopPropagation`, you won't see the event (since that stops it bubbling to the document). Here's an example of both when it reaches the document and when it doesn't:

```js
document.getElementById("workedButton").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    console.log(`button click on #${event.currentTarget.id}`);
});
document.getElementById("blockedButton").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    console.log(`button click on #${event.currentTarget.id}`);
});
document.getElementById("blocker").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    console.log("blocked");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const node = event.target.closest("#workedButton, #blockedButton");
    if (node) {
        console.log(`document click on #${node.id}`);
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="workedButton" value="Works">
<div id="blocker">
    <input type="button" id="blockedButton" value="Blocked">
</div>
```

Comment: Each of these options has pros & cons to consider. If you use a Promise it'll run almost immediately - _before_ the event continues bubbling. If you use a 0ms `setTimeout()`, that may wait _longer_ than the end of bubbling in some cases: e.g. if the event is `mouseup` it won't run until after the corresponding `click` event is also fully done bubbling up. If you handle the event on `document`, you could possibly miss getting called at all if anyone in the bubbling chain calls `stopPropagation()`.

Comment: @peterflynn - Yeah, that's what I meant by "before any queued events" but I should make that more explicit. I'll add a note about `stopPropagation` as well, surprised I didn't mention that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Then you should add an event listener to the document object, that is the last DOM "element" that recognizes an event, all of the events will have bubbled up to document.